# Convert Indesign content to LaTeX?

Tags: conversion, adobe

Are there any tools for migrating the content of an Indesign document to LaTeX markup?

I guess some preprocessing, and a lot of postprocessing would be needed. I am only looking for the most basic *content* migration – not the layout/typography.

Something like:

- Body text typography style --> `text`
- Header 1 typography style --> `\chapter`
- Header 2 typography style --> `\section`

Wishful wish list:

- footnotes
- figures
- …

Comment: Googling doesn't really give anything useful: http://www.google.com/search?q=export+indesign+to+latex Only LaTeX to Indesign and mostly concerning math.

Comment: (I'm wondering if this is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)  It's not likely that you'll find a good, general solution -- maybe specific things *within* an InDesign document, but layout will die, etc. etc.

Comment: @SeanAllred Well, I hope there might be a good, general solution for migrating content from Indesign documents to LaTeX markup – similar to Markdown --> LaTeX or Doc --> LaTeX. I have a document (a book, ca 300 pages with illustrations) would like to migrate the whole project to LaTeX with as little manual copying and pasting as possible.

Comment: I would say that, aside, it might be more troublesome than it's worth---no conversion is perfect.  Are you converting to LaTeX to simplify the maintenance of the text, or for some other reason?  Have you considered LaTeX->RTF->InDesign?

Comment: You mean Indesign -> RTF -> LaTeX? Haven't tried that, maybe an idea. As long as I can get the body text as text, a few header levels converted, some `\includegraphics`it would surely be worth it.

Comment: InDesign can export to XML and use XSLT so there may be some way to leverage that into LaTeX, but I've never tried it.